# using sqlalchemy to_sql when dataframe has different column names to sql server table column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a dataframe that I upload to a SQL server table. I am using sqlalchemy & the to_sql method.

The data uploads into the table perfectly. Currently I have designed it so that my column names in my dataframe and sql table are the same. However I was wondering if this needs to be the case? Is there a way that when your dataframe has a different column name to the sql table that you can specify some mapping? Or do you just simply rename the column name in your dataframe?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(engine_str)
conn = engine.connect()
df.to_sql(tbl_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: This is a good question, did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this situation when transferring data between tables, I've used **pandas.DataFrame.rename** to map one set of columns to another before pushing the dataframe back to SQL.

So, for example let's say that one table has the columns: **Name**, **IPAddress**, **Folder**

And your second table has the columns: **name**, **ip**, **folder**

You could read the first table with sqlalchemy into a dataframe:

```
source_data = pd.read_sql_table(source_table, con=engine)
```

Then create a conversion dictionary to convert the columns:

```
conv_dict = {
'Name': 'name',
'IPAddress': 'ip',
'Folder': 'folder'
}

# convert the columns into a new datframe
new_df = source_data.rename(columns=conv_dict)
```

Now you can put that new dataframe with the converted columns into your second table:

```
new_df.to_sql(dest_table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html